# Is the expansion of Ego's seed referenced anywhere else in MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

In the second half of Guardians of the Galaxy vol. 2 Ego activates the seeds

> he had planted on various planets and they start violently expanding, wreaking havoc and causing havoc all around.

This takes place in 2014, when there are at least a couple organisations functioning with the purpose of protecting Earth from extraordinary threats, including S.H.I.E.L.D. and Ancient One's flock. Is there any evidence that they have investigated this incident?